# How do I fill multiple chests with hoppers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a mob spawner (the KaspersMC type, a 9*9*5 room that uses water to push mobs down a hole.)

At the bottom of the drop hole I have a hopper feeding a double chest. So when I kill the mobs all their drops go into the hopper, and then into the double chest.

How can I expand this to include more than one double chest?

Here's an image of what I want to do.  This obviously doesn't work.

[image]

I don't care what order stuff fills.  I don't care about sorting. I don't care if the hoppers store stuff (so long as that doesn't block anything.)

This is on the "pc" version, offline, no mods, not a server, vanilla etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hoppers collect items **from above only**. Either they are directly falling into the hopper, or there is a box on top of the hopper containing items.

However, they can push items into e.g. a chest either below or besides them.

Because of this, your items will be stored in the left chest, but they will not be pulled out by the right hopper and placed in the right chest.

You can build something like this (side view):

```
 --------
| Hopper |
|pointing|
|  down  |
 --------
|        |
| Chest  |          (chest below hopper)
|        |
 -----------------
| Hopper |        |
|pointing| Chest  | (chest aside of hopper)
|  right |        |
 -----------------
```

Comment: Hoppers collect from above only, *but can have items placed into them by other hoppers or by droppers.*